# Have to print to screen for program to work

Tags: c++

So, my program has run into some wierd issue where if I write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int);

int main()
{
    int biggestPalindrome = 0;
    for(int i = 999; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for(int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            cout << "Hello" << endl; // This part
            if(isPalindrome(i * j) && i * j > biggestPalindrome) biggestPalindrome = i * j;
            if(i * j < biggestPalindrome) break;
        }
        if(i * (i-1) < biggestPalindrome) break;
    }
    cout << biggestPalindrome;
}

bool isPalindrome(int number)
{
    int temp, rev, digit;
    temp = number;
    do
    {
        digit = number % 10;
        rev = (rev * 10) + digit;
        number /= 10;
    } while(number != 0);
    return temp == rev;
}
```

The program runs fine in this case, but when I comment out the 15th line ('cout << "Hello" << endl;') the program directly returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

In the function `isPalindrome`, the value of `rev` is used without initializing that.

It means you are using indeterminate value.

Add `ret = 0;` before the loop to fix.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it fixed the problem. Just wondering though, why would it work when I print out test?

Comment: With undefined behavior anything can happen. One of the most unfortunate behaviors of UB is the program appears to work when its broken.

Comment: @Joel Basically the compiler tries to rearrange your program to make it faster (this is called optimization). When you put the print there, it rearranges it differently. This is the usual reason why "undefined behaviour" can cause weird things to happen.